# iOS Screenshot plugin on PhoneGap 2.1

Tags: ios, cordova, screenshot

I'm trying to use iOS PhoneGap Screenshot plugin on PhoneGap 2.1.

This is my Screenshot.m file (put in Plugind folder).

```
//
//  Screenshot.h
//
//  Created by Simon Madine on 29/04/2010.
//  Copyright 2010 The Angry Robot Zombie Factory.
//   - Converted to Cordova 1.6.1 by Josemando Sobral.
//  MIT licensed
//
//  Modifications to support orientation change by @ffd8
//

#import "Screenshot.h"

@implementation Screenshot

@synthesize webView;

- (void)saveScreenshot:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options
{
    CGRect imageRect;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    // statusBarOrientation is more reliable than UIDevice.orientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) { 
        // landscape check
        imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetHeight(screenRect), CGRectGetWidth(screenRect));
    } else {
        // portrait check
        imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(screenRect), CGRectGetHeight(screenRect));
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, 0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);

    [webView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Image Saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

@end
```

This is my Screenshot.h file, put in Plugins folder :

```
//
//  Screenshot.h
//
//  Created by Simon Madine on 29/04/2010.
//  Copyright 2010 The Angry Robot Zombie Factory.
//   - Converted to Cordova 1.6.1 by Josemando Sobral.
//  MIT licensed
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@interface Screenshot : CDVPlugin {
}

- (void)saveScreenshot:(NSArray*)arguments withDict:(NSDictionary*)options;

@end
```

This is my Screenshot.js file put in www folder

```
 /*
 *  This code is adapted from the work of Michael Nachbaur 
 *  by Simon Madine of The Angry Robot Zombie Factory
 *   - Converted to Cordova 1.6.1 by Josemando Sobral.
 *  2012-07-03
 *  MIT licensed
 */

/*
 * Temporary Scope to contain the plugin.
 *  - More information here:
 *     https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md
 */
(function() {
    /* Get local ref to global PhoneGap/Cordova/cordova object for exec function.
        - This increases the compatibility of the plugin. */
    var cordovaRef = window.PhoneGap || window.Cordova || window.cordova; // old to new fallbacks

    /**
     * This class exposes the ability to take a Screenshot to JavaScript
     */
 function Screenshot() { }

    /**
     * Save the screenshot to the user's Photo Library
     */
    Screenshot.prototype.saveScreenshot = function() {
        cordovaRef.exec(null, null, "Screenshot", "saveScreenshot", []);
    };


    cordovaRef.addConstructor(function() {
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }
        if (!window.plugins.Screenshot) {
            window.plugins.Screenshot = new Screenshot();
        }
    });

 })(); /* End of Temporary Scope. */
```

I call my function is script.js with this line :  `window.plugins.Screenshot.saveScreenshot() ;`

I've already added Screenshot plugin in Cordova.plist

Now I'm running application, no compile error, but JS doesn't works and I've no screenshot in image app.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you add corresponding entry in [Cordova.plist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html)? <key>Screenshot</key> <string>Screenshot</string>

Comment: can you post the script.js content too? or it just contains window.plugins.Screenshot.saveScreenshot();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't paste the Script.js code, but I think I know what your problem is.
You are calling the plugin on document ready, but to call a plugin you have to wait for device ready

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // Cordova is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.plugins.Screenshot.saveScreenshot() ;
    }
```

Comment: I have "$(document).ready(function(){" at the beginning of script.js.

But I don't understand why this plugin doesn't works because I use also notification plugin and it works.

Comment: Yes, you have $(document).ready, but you need deviceready too, sometimes the document is ready, but the device is not, you have to wait for the deviceready if you want to use the plugin. You are calling the screenshot plugin when the document is ready, and maybe the device isn't ready yet. And when you call later the notification plugin, the device is ready and it works. Anyways, if you try with the deviceready and still doesn't work, I'll check the plugin code this afternoon.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem ! Thanks a lot ! It was just missing device ready you're right